# Problemas com Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, servidor

Tenho uma aplicação web Java, instalado em um Windows Server. Ao Startar o tomcat, ele funciona normalmente, e endereços como:

```
http://localhost:8085
```

e

```
http://localhost:8085/examples
```

(exemplos que já vem com o tomcat)

Funcionam normalmente, porem quando tento acessar minha aplicação:

```
http://localhost:8085/minha-aplicacao
```

Tenho o erro **404**.

O que me deixa mais confuso, é que em meu notebook de desenvolvimento, funciona normalmente, sendo as mesmas configurações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O servidor Tomcat pode funcionar normalmente, incluindo várias aplicações instaladas nele, porém a sua aplicação não está inicializada.

Quando o Tomcat inicializa, ele faz o deploy de todas as aplicações configuradas, uma a uma, criando o contexto de cada uma para depois servir as requisições.

Entretanto, se durante o *deploy* de uma das aplicações ocorrer um erro, o contexto dela é descartado e o Tomcat continua suas operações normalmente.

As causas mais comuns de uma aplicação que funciona localmente, mas não em outro servidor são:

1. **Diferença de ambiente**: banco de dados ou outros recursos não estão disponíveisou estão com dados de acesso modificados.
2. **Configuração incorreta**: pode ser que falte alguma configuração. Verifique se o `context.xml` da sua aplicação tem os dados corretos para os `DataSources` necessários. Verifique também se a aplicação possui dependências de arquivos ou diretórios (logs, properties, ...).
3. **Diferença no WAR**: pode ser que o WAR usado no servidor não tenha o mesmo conteúdo que está sendo usado no ambiente de desenvolvimento. Neste caso, verificar o procedimento de geração de versão.
4. **Diferença do Tomcat**: verifique se há libs (jars) diferentes entre a sua instalação do Tomcat a a que está no servidor, pois estar faltando ou sobrando classes e gerando problemas de *class loaders*. Verifique também se falta algo no `server.xml` ou no `context.xml` geral do Tomcat. Já vi algumas aplicações que precisavam de configurações específicas no `catalina.properties`.

É bom comparar os arquivos dos Tomcats. Também é bom verificar se o sistema tem algum manual de instalação onde possa descrever o procedimento para *deploy* num Tomcat "novo".

A principal dica é sempre começar analisando os logs gerados pelo Tomcat durante a tentativa de iniciar a aplicação. Quase sempre ele vai dar a solução ou pelo menos uma dica.

Comment: sabe também se pode ser alguma diferença ou permissão na questão do sistema operacional? Pois por desencargo, eu copiei a pasta completa do tomcat7, de minha máquina e colei no servidor, então, as opções 3 e 4 podem estar praticamente descartadas. Pois o tomcat e war é o mesmo. Logo vou fazer o que me indicou na opção 2. A opção 1, mesmo uma página que não teria acesso a base de dados, não traria o erro 404, ou traria?

Comment: @EricoSouza O erro 404 indica que a página não foi encontrada, portanto a aplicação não está iniciada. O motivo para ela não estar iniciada pode ser qualquer um, desde um erro grave na aplicação até a URL digitada incorretamente. Pode ser que tenha algo a ver com o sistema permissão, principalmente se a aplicação acessa algum recurso local. Não esqueça de ver o log.

Comment: Consegui ver aqui, no log do tomcat, ele me da esse erro: **threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak**, já é um caminho.

Comment: @EricoSouza Este é apenas um *warning*, não chega a ser um erro. Pare o Tomcat, delete os arquivos de log, remova as outras aplicações deixando apenas a que está com problemas, inicie novamente o Tomcat e então olhe todos os logs com atenção para encontrar problemas.

Comment: @EricoSouza Se quiser pode colocar um link para os logs que eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda @utluiz, se não for incomodo, fiz como você me indicou, e aqui estão os links dos logs:
http://www.ericosouza.com/log/catalina.2015-01-06.txt
e
http://www.ericosouza.com/log/localhost.2015-01-06.txt